# How to restore prebuilt files after accidentally deleting?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I ran the command:

```
$ git clean -fd
```

> Removing cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/gen/
>   Removing cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/libs/
>   Removing cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/local.properties
>   Removing cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/res/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/win10/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/winrt_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/chipmunk/prebuilt/wp_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/winrt_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/curl/prebuilt/wp_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/win10/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/winrt_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/wp_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/glfw3/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/jpeg/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/linux-specific/fmod/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/png/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/sqlite3/libraries/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/tiff/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/webp/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/ios/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/linux/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/win10/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/win32/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/winrt_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/websockets/prebuilt/wp_8.1/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win10-specific/OggDecoder/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win10-specific/angle/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win10-specific/zlib/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/MP3Decoder/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/OggDecoder/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/OpenalSoft/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/gles/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/icon/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/win32-specific/zlib/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/winrt-specific/angle/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/winrt-specific/zlib/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/winrt_8.1-specific/OggDecoder/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/winrt_8.1-specific/angle/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/winrt_8.1-specific/zlib/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/wp_8.1-specific/OggDecoder/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/wp_8.1-specific/angle/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/wp_8.1-specific/zlib/prebuilt/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/android/armeabi-v7a/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/android/armeabi/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/android/x86/
>   Removing cocos2d/external/zlib/prebuilt/mac/
>   Removing cocos2d/plugin/plugins/qh360/proj.android/CLibs/
>   Removing proj.android/assets/
>   Removing proj.android/gen/
>   Removing proj.android/libs/

So now when I run:

> cocos run -p android

Compilation fails with error :

> Android NDK: ERROR:/Users/power/Documents/Projects/spacegame/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk:cocos_freetype2_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
>   Android NDK: Check that /Users/power/Documents/Projects/spacegame/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/armeabi/libfreetype.a exists  or that its path is correct
>   make: Entering directory `/Users/power/Documents/Projects/spacegame/proj.android'
>   /Applications/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
>   make: Leaving directory`/Users/power/Documents/Projects/spacegame/proj.android'
>   Error running command, return code: 2.

How can I fix this ? I've done git clean before, but I didn't get this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new project with cocos new, and copied the missing directories. Seems to work.